# Outlook close to tray

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep outlook 2010 open](https://superuser.com/questions/199786/keep-outlook-2010-open)

Ok, I'm stuck using outlook in the office 2010 and one thing I'll always rant about outlook in any version is that when I press the X button it goes away.

I mean, I know the X button is supposed to close the app, it's the standard and all that, but email is (sadly) very critical, as well as meeting requests and reminders, outlook should not be closed so freaking easily. I mean, Live Messenger is not so critical but it has this feature built in and on by default.

Is there a way to close outlook to the tray, addons, vba, settings, reghack, anything?

I know there is minimize to tray and I've been searching the web but could not find anything useful.

Comment: What version of Outlook you are using now ?

Comment: This showed up as the first result when searching from Google - I'd just like to point out that there's a free utility as answer to the other question (although, perhaps not for Outlook 2010): http://superuser.com/questions/189905/how-to-make-outlook-2010-minimize-when-i-try-to-close-it

Answer (score 1):

There is article and addon to prevent closing outlook by hooking the close event and author claims that it works well on outlook2007. *haven't tested this one personally*

http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2007/04/14/preventing-outlook-from-closing-with-alt-f4.aspx

and addon -> http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/attachment/2240289.ashx

Comment: works for 2007, but not for 2010 beta, which is the one I'm  currently using. Being a developer I tried to upgrade the addon but seems something changed from 07 to 10 that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst it is not a direct solution [Trayer](http://www.kfsoft.com/trayer/index.htm) is a util which allows any app to be minimised to the systray - but it includes an option to disable the Close button on a per app basis.

> **Disable Window's Close (X) Button**
>
> If you find yourself closing an
> application by accident too easily
> instead of minimize it and hide it,
> this tweak can help.

[image]

Comment: This is almost what I need. It provides a way to hide the app, provides a way to block the close button. But it does not store my settings, it means that every shut down I have to reconfigure. another drawback is that is just 30 days trial. License costs 12 bucks.

Comment: @David-Lay - I think it does save settings once you pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

One side route to get this functionality I've found is that if you have a minimized window that is hidden to task bar then open a second window and close that outlook stays running.

Just use the quick launch icon every time you want to get back into outlook. You can close these windows as you will because you have the 'Prime' window running in the system tray.

If you want to close outlook just right-click/close or open up that last window and close it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Actual Window Manager](http://www.actualtools.com/windowmanager/) will do what you want.