# Add send/receive to Outlook systray icon?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, notification-area

Is it possible to add a send/receive action to the Outlook 2007 system tray right-click context menu? It's a little annoying to have to open the whole interface just to run this simple action manually. I have searched for an answer, but could only find two other [unanswered](http://www.office-outlook.com/outlook-forum/index.php/m/673436/) [questions](http://www.eqna.org/63979/can-i-add-a-send-receive-button-to-the-outlook-system-tray-logo).

If there's no particular answer as of yet, would it make more sense to explore making a plug-in like [this one to keep running in the systray when closed](https://superuser.com/a/275244/94821), or to look for a registry hack, or something else entirely?

Comment: Excuse me, but I currently don't get it. Why would you want to start this action manually and not configure it to happen automatically?

Comment: As it is, I can only configure it to check every x minutes, as my business doesn't have an Exchange server set up (no push). Because I am a refresh monkey, it's more to soothe my occasional procrastination than anything.

I realise it is a little silly, and it's even a little academic because we will _eventually_ be getting an Exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use http://www.autohotkey.com/ to create a script that activates Outlook window, sends keystrokes to send/receive, then minimizes Outlook window or something similar.  Then, create a shortcut to this script, assign it a hotkey key combination in the shortcut, and push those keys to make this script run real fast and then get back out of your way.