# How to make Outlook 2010 warn user before exit?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Company has Outlook 2010 clients in use with an Exchange Server. The user accidentally closes the Outlook window and forgets that it is not open: the whole day may be gone without noticing.

One may not *favor* the "do you really want to do it" style dialogs of Microsoft fame, but in this specific scenario, it would be good if the user could *voluntarily* configure it to warn her/him and ask again what to do.

What I've tried, via [a thread on answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-outlook/outlook-warn-me-before-exiting/2d11fe35-4389-44e2-8055-fc6350160fce), is this solution from [slipstick.com](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/how-to-stop-accidentally-closing-outlook/), basically:

1. Open a new message – enter eg. "*`Keep the window open`*" as the `subject`. Don’t enter an address in the `To` field!
2. Save the message to `Drafts`.
   Drag it from `Drafts` to the `Outbox` (*not* "Sent Mail").
3. If using 2010, Switch to the Options tab
4. If using 2010, Click the Delay Delivery button and enter a future date (a year or so should be fine.)
5. When you exit Outlook, you’ll have the chance to cancel closing Outlook.

But article also warns that,

```
Please note, this only works in cached mode.
Delayed messages are stored on Exchange server in classic online mode.
```

Outlook here [is in cached mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP001232935.aspx#BM5) but still the method doesn't seem to have the effect.

Is there a way to make Outlook (2010) issue a warning (dialog?) before exiting? To ask the user whether he/she wants to exit?

Comment: You may have to just run a script which fires every hour, detects if it's closed or not, and if so, open it. You can't really do this via VBa, Private Sub Application_Quit() (no overload for cancel the quit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this does not answer the actual question but it helps to resolve the problem you are describing. There is the way to prevent Outlook from closing. This method will force outlook to minimize to tray when close using (X) button or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

1. Download [KeepOutlookRunning.dll](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepoutlook/files/0.0.1/) (for your 32- or 64-bit system)
2. Start Outlook as Administrator (right click on it in Start Menu)
3. Go to File -> Options -> Add-Ins
4. At the bottom: Manage [COM-Addins] press [Go...] [Add...] the KeepOutlookRunning.dll file downloaded in step 2
5. Restart Outlook as a normal user

Outlook will be minimized instead of closing. To actual exit the program user can use File> Exit

The answer is taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/275244/281154). If it has helped you, please go and ++ original author, not me.

Comment: it really is something else but is nevertheless good enough in my situation. thanks!